# how to search user input against a list in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to create a simple program in ruby that will let me insert a bulk list of device IMEI numbers to check if they were already processed. Whenever I run the following code it always responds with "IMEI Not Found in database". It will reply with the last line of code always. Ive been researching for a couple days now and have decided to make a post now after being unsuccessful. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
imei_database = ["1", "2", "3"]
puts "Enter IMEIs"
imei = gets
if imei_database.include?(imei)
  puts "IMEI Found in database"
else
  puts "IMEI Not Found in database"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `.chomp` your input to remove a trailing newline. You can debug this by using `p imei` to see what you're dealing with. The input must also be a single number, e.g. type `1`, contrary to the plural `"IMEIs"` prompted by the UI.

Comment: Thank you @Rajagopalan!!

Comment: Would it be possible to input a bulk list of numbers in the command prompt to check multiple at once? @ggorlen

Comment: Of course it's possible but you'll need to write different code to do that. Split the input on some delimiter (whitespace?) and iterate using a loop over the elements in the array, testing each one against the "database".

Comment: `imei = imei.gsub("\n","")` also works.

Comment: `imei = gets.scan /\d+/`  works for the example inputs too, and (perhaps non-intuitively) still returns a an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

### Problems

Your current code doesn't use [String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-chomp) or other methods to remove the trailing carriage return from [Kernel#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). You are actually getting values like `"1\n"`, so you won't find a match in your *imei_database* array.

You also haven't implemented any splitting, pattern matching, or parsing of your input values, so you currently can't process more than one item at a time. You'll need to iterate over some collection constructed from your input to do that.

### Suggested Solutions

Here's some alternate code that shows one way to get the results you want, but in a more modular way. Note that the core of the heavy lifting is done with `gets.chomp.split`, which is a simple way to handle multi-valued input strings.

```rb
class IMEI_Status
  def initialize
    @imei_status = {}
    imei_input
  end 

  def report
    found     = 'IMEI Found in Database: %s'
    not_found = 'IMEI Not Found in Database: %s'

    @imei_status.map do |k, v|
      p((v ? found : not_found) % k)
    end 
  end 
  
  private

  def db_lookup
    # stubbed response
    %w[1 2 3]
  end 

  def imei_lookup(imei)
    db_lookup.include? imei
  end 

  def imei_input
    print 'Enter space-separated IMEIs: '
    gets.chomp.split.each do |imei|
      @imei_status[imei] = imei_lookup(imei)
    end 
    @imei_status
  end 
end
```

```rb
# Testing, using `1 4` as user input.

status = IMEI_Status.new
status.report
#=> ["IMEI Found in Database: 1", "IMEI Not Found in Database: 4"]
```

There are certainly other ways to deliver similar results, so you can adapt the approach to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Newline character escape required!

```
imei_database = ["1", "2", "3"]
puts "Enter IMEIs"
imei = gets
imei = imei.chomp

if imei_database.include?(imei)
   puts "IMEI Found in database"
else
   puts "IMEI Not Found in database"
end
```

`imei = imei.gsub("\n","")`

works too.

Answer (score 0):

If `item_database` is large, many user entries are anticipated and execution speed is paramount you should use a proper database or first convert `item_database` to a set, assuming sufficient memory is available. Set lookups are very fast, nearly constant-time, comparable to key lookups in hashes (which is not suprising considering that sets are implemented with a hash under the covers).

```
require 'set'

imei_database = ["1", "2", "3"]
IMEI_DATABASE_SET = imei_database.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"1", "2", "3"}>
```

Then execute:

```
entry = gets.chomp
puts "IMEI #{entry}#{IMEI_DATABASE_SET.include?(entry) ? '' : ' Not'} Found in database"
```

Two examples:

```
entry = "2\n".chomp
  #=> "2"
puts "IMEI #{entry}#{IMEI_DATABASE_SET.include?(entry) ? '' : ' Not'} Found in database"
IMEI 2 Found in database
```

```
entry = "4\n".chomp
  #=> "4" 
puts "IMEI #{entry}#{IMEI_DATABASE_SET.include?(entry) ? '' : ' Not'} Found in database"
IMEI 4 Not Found in database
```